# jQuery: using autocomplete to populate two input fileds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jQuery UI (autocomplete) to populate an input field with name of songs. The script is like this:

```
        $(function() 
    {
        var availableTags = <?php include('db/autoSongKomponist.php'); ?>;

        $("#inputTitel").autocomplete({
           source: availableTags,
           autoFocus:true
        });
    });
```

The PHP-Script will return the songs in JSON:

```
var availableTags = ["Not Fade Away","Route 66", ....];
```

So far it work fine. What I would like to do is following. After choosing a song title I would like to get in a second input field the name of the composer.

It works with select in this way:

```
        function getKomponist(val) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'getKomponistName.php',
            data: {
                get_option:val
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#inputKomponist").append(response); 
            }
        });
    }
```

I can fill #inputKomponist with the right value(s) for a select.

```
  <select id="inputKomponist"></select>
```

The PHP-Script will do something like this:

```
$name = $_POST['get_option'];
$result = mysql_query("select komponist from songs where name='$name'");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    echo "<option>" . $row['komponist'] . "</option>";
}
```

I also tried it to put the values in an input field instead of select, e.g.

```
        function getKomponist(val)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'readKomponistName.php',
            data: {
                get_option:val
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#inputKomponist").autocomplete({
                    source: response,
                    autoFocus:true
                });
            }
         });
    }
```

But it won't work, can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: can you post your table properties ?

Comment: As I understand, after selecting song you want receive the corresponding composer and put it into another input? Why you try to put the name of the composer in the second input field with autocomplete? You can do `$("#inputKomponist").val(response)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I try to put the composer in a second input field because for some of the songs there's no composer, some have only one and other songs have the same title but from various groups with different composer.